# How to do a reverse proxy with node.js for a shiny app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, shiny, reverse-proxy

EDIT

I think the problem might be that the WebSocket connection does not go through the proxy node.js. How to authorize the connection of the WebSocket?

---

I have a web app hosted on a nodeJS server. On the same vm I also have a shiny serveur hosting an app. I use node to redirect traffic to port 3838 (shiny) when a somes URL are requested.

I use this code on node :

```
app.use('/the-shiny-app', proxy({target: 'http://localhost:3838', changeOrigin: true}));
```

With this setting everything works fine on the shiny app when I go on mydomain/the-shiny-app/* except when I try to run code in a code box.

When I try to run code I get this error on the chrome console :

```
 Connection closed. Info: {"type":"close","code":4503,"reason":"The application unexpectedly exited","wasClean":true}
```

An example of what I mean by code box :

[image]

if I do not use node.js and I redirect the traffic (on OS level) from port 80 directly to 3838 everything works fine.

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3838
```

I do not know exactly what kind of exchange is made between the browser and the shiny server when we run code, but maybe the protocol used is blocked by node.js.

Comment: Using nginx as reverse proxy you would need to use `proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";` but I haven't got a clue on how to do this with shining... https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/
Why not use nginx as reverse proxy to do this for you?

Comment: OK, thanks. The proxy is on node.js (express) I'm now using http-proxy-middleware and I add   `ws: true,  // proxy websockets`.  I thing I also have to add `External WebSocket upgrade` as you said. I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. As Antony Gibbs said you need to setup a WebSocket upgrade. I'm using http-proxy-middleware you cans find the doc here : https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware